# easy-autocomplete not working after internationalization (i18n)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Since I internationalized my app with i18n, easy-autocomplete return the following error:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (MainController#search is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["application/json"]
request.variant: []):
```

Is anybody familiar with this ? what should I add/modify please ?

Comment: There should be a `*.json` file somewhere, which contains the list where the autocomplete javascript looks. Check if it exists and is build properly.

Comment: I suppose posting the contents of app/views/main would help. Default file format for Rails 5 would be search.json.jbuilder.